# ROS2 Topic is sent twice

Tags: ros-humble

Hello ladies and gents of this fabulous robotics stackexchange!

I'm currently on my first ROS2 project - currently on my Master Thesis. (I did work with ROS1 a few years in my last job)

I do have a strange problem, that my message is published twice without any clue why.

So my current project is a mostly "trigger-based". It's a design choice, feel free to say why I shoudn't do it or if that's good, but that's probably not the issue.

So node1 publishes a topic, that node2 (and node3, node4) receives. The callback does some calculations, creates a new message, and calls the publisher of the new topic.

I receive the message of node1 in multiple nodes, but only one does have problems.
The message that is sent by node2 is sent multiple times.

The thing is:
I stripped down this callback as much as possible:

```
def robot_state_listener_callback(self, robot_state_msg):
        # strip down for debug
        target_point = Point(0.0,0.0,0.0)

        # publish debug stuff
        debug_msg = MachineDebug()
        debug_msg.target_point_on_path_x = target_point.x
        debug_msg.target_point_on_path_y = target_point.y
        debug_msg.target_point_on_path_theta = target_point.theta
        # assign cycle id -> robot_state is source!
        debug_msg.cycle = robot_state_msg.cycle

        
        self.get_logger().warning('Debug Counter before: "%s"' % self.number_debug)
        self.debug_publisher_.publish(debug_msg)
        self.get_logger().warning('Debug Counter after: "%s"' % self.number_debug)
        self.number_debug += 1
```

Of course there is only one subscriber for it in the __ init__ function of the node:

```
        # subscriber
        self.robot_state_subscriber = self.create_subscription(
            RobotState, 
            'robot_state', 
            self.robot_state_listener_callback, 
            10)
```

The warning outputs (Debug Counter before / after) are only executed once per second. That's the cycle of the robot_state_msg.

**But the message that is published, is sent twice.** Basically at the same time. Before I stripped it down that much, even the content was sometimes different (not possible anymore, because mostly static).

I honestly don't have any idea what the Issue could be. Is it because of my Point(..) class? That lib is included in multiple nodes, that Class is used quite often.
Some timing issues? I do have 5 nodes, 3 of them are subscribing the robot_state and using it for some calculations.
I'm honestly lost currently....

Any help?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Based on what do you conclude that it is sent twice?

Comment: In addition to @JRTG's question, it would be helpful to look at what nodes are making use of this topic (for example, using 'rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph' or 'rostopic info'). That would help determine if your node has a bug, or if it's because you have more nodes than you expected.

Comment: @JRTG
Well, if I just check on everywhere: ros2 topic echo, rqt, etc. I see the frequency is doubled. I see two messages in echo, etc.

Comment: @cst0 I do only have one node, it's only sent by this one node. Everything is strange.

Comment: But important: I don't have this issue today. What the fuck did I do differently yesterday?
At least it's nothing common, so maybe I did something wrong yesterday? Idk....

Genuine question, that might be something I did differently sometimes:
Is it important **after** I build, to source it (source install/setup.bash) if I'm still in the same terminal?

Comment: I personally source every time in case if I make noticeable changes. That prevents me from having a lot of unnecessary hassle.

Answer (score 0):

Given the remarks in the comments, I conclude that @cst0 is probably right and you had two publisher nodes running without realizing.

Typical reason is e.g. that you run it in a terminal on one desktop, then swich to another desktop where you are editing the code, compile and run again but forget to switch back to the desktop where the original node is still running.

I also have a vague memory of similar behavior when a launch file was interrupted and hence did not gracefully stop all launched nodes, but I don't recall the details.

In any case, as @cst0 suggested: `ros2 run rqt_graph rqt_graph` will show you the graph, or simply `ros2 node list` can also show you if duplicate nodes are running.

Wrt. sourcing: you typically need to source setup.bash only once, except e.g. if you add a new package to your workspace.

Comment: Well, sadly that was not the case. I only have one terminator that I use for everything. Also checked with rqt_graph. But like I said, I struggled for several hours before calling it a day, and didn't have this issue since then. So maybe there was some problems with the OS in the background...